# Configure emacs to insert spaces when pressing the the tab key

Tags: emacs

How can I configure emacs so that when I press the the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key it inserts spaces?

Comment: @Eight - not sure this is a "find and replace" issue. It could be simply asking how to make "tab" produce spaces, from now on.

Comment: There's probably a better tag to go along with emacs here. @gno

Comment: yes, this isn't find and replace. I want tab to produce spaces :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To configure Emacs so that pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will produce spaces instead of actual tab characters:

> `M-x set-variable<RET>
>   indent-tabs-mode<RET> nil`
>
> Or in your .emacs file:
>
> `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`

*From [this page](http://notfaq.wordpress.com/2006/08/17/emacs-tab-vs-space/).*

Comment: (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil) worked!!!!

Comment: Note that there's more to this than meets the eye in Emacs. See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryIndentation for details.